# What copper oxide is being created upon electrolysis?

Tags: home-experiment, electrolysis, identification

Whenever using copper as anode, I end up with cyan dust that doesn't dissolve in water.

[image: mysterious copper oxide]

What's that (presumably) oxide? Is it poisonous? Can I dissolve it in something to perform electroplating with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be copper hydroxide or copper carbonate.  Copper oxide tends to be black/grey/brown.  Copper hydroxide is blue and copper carbonate is green.  Copper carbonate forms when the hydroxide is exposed to CO2.

If you would like to dissolve it, try an acidic solution.

Comment: I would like to dissolve it in order to perform electroplating with it. Would it work?

Comment: I find that copper chloride solutions tend to be the most reactive.  If I were you I'd try dissolving it in HCl.  It will dissolve in acid and should work for electroplating.

Comment: I have dissolved it in sulphuric acid since hydrochloric was harder to obtain at the moment. The copper won't stick to most surfaces however. It just forms dust around them.

Comment: It should stick to a metallic surface.  Insure that the metal surface is free of corrosion by pickling.